# Problem installing Steam

Tags: steam

I have a problem when installing Steam on Ubuntu. It keeps saying :

> Fatal Error: Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network and try again.

What should I do?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32001/discussion-on-question-by-white-problem-installing-steam).